# Optimizing Sqlite query: grouping in subqueries

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite

I have a pretty simple Sqlite schema for recording daily counts by user action and various user action latency percentiles by day and action:

```
create table user_actions (
  id integer primary key,
  name text not null
)

create table action_date_count (
  action_id integer not null
    references user_actions(id) on delete restrict on update restrict,
  date integer not null,
  count integer not null,
  unique (action_id, date) on conflict fail
)

create table latency_percentiles (
  action_id integer not null
    references user_actions(id) on delete restrict on update restrict,
  date integer not null,
  percentile integer not null,
  value real not null,
  unique (action_id, date, percentile) on conflict fail
)
```

Here all dates are stored as Unix timestamps of midnight of each day (I can change that if it helps).

Now here is a query I am struggling with: show actions sorted descending by average volume over the last week, include average latency percentiles at 50%, 90%, 95% levels.  I came up with a huge query that explain plan says takes 17 steps, and it is pretty slow.  Can anybody improve it?

```
select ua.id, ua.name, ac.avg_count, al50.avg_lat_50, al90.avg_lat_90, al95.avg_lat_95
  from
    user_actions as ua,
    (
      select adc.action_id as action_id, avg(adc.count) as avg_count
      from
        action_date_count as adc,
        (select max(date) as max_date from action_date_count) as md
      where
        julianday(md.max_date, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') - julianday(adc.date, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') between 1 and 7
      group by action_id
    ) as ac,
    (
      select lp.action_id as action_id, avg(lp.value) as avg_lat_50
      from
        latency_percentiles as lp,
        (select max(date) as max_date from action_date_count) as md
      where
        lp.percentile = 50 and
        julianday(md.max_date, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') - julianday(lp.date, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') between 1 and 7
      group by action_id
    ) as al50,
    (
      select lp.action_id as action_id, avg(lp.value) as avg_lat_90
      from
        latency_percentiles as lp,
        (select max(date) as max_date from action_date_count) as md
      where
        lp.percentile = 90 and
        julianday(md.max_date, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') - julianday(lp.date, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') between 1 and 7
      group by action_id
    ) as al90,
    (
      select lp.action_id as action_id, avg(lp.value) as avg_lat_95
      from
        latency_percentiles as lp,
        (select max(date) as max_date from action_date_count) as md
      where
        lp.percentile = 95 and
        julianday(md.max_date, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') - julianday(lp.date, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') between 1 and 7
      group by action_id
    ) as al95
  where ua.id = ac.action_id and ua.id = al50.action_id and ua.id = al90.action_id and ua.id = al95.action_id
  order by ac.avg_count desc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have indexed the `date` columns on `action_date_count` and `latency_percentiles` tables.

The problem then is that sqlite cannot use the date index given the query you provided. You can fix this by adjusting your date comparisons.

**Instead of this:**

```
julianday(md.max_date, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') - julianday(lp.date, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') between 1 and 7
```

**Do this:**

```
lp.date between md.max_date - 7 * 24 * 3600 and md.max_date
```

You may also get good results by creating a covering index on `latency_percentiles (date, percentile, value)`. YMMV.